# GDB string file syntax error

Tags: ubuntu, gdb

recently Im unable to debug any binary using gdb and get always the same error - "exec  - syntax error"

for example, when I try gdb ls (after gdb starts and I press 'r'), the following error appear:

> Starting Program : /bin/ls
>
> File "< string>" , line 1
>
> exec /bin/ls
>
> SyntaxError : Invalid syntax

Things tried so far:
1) purge and reinstall gdb
2) massive google search

thank you in advance for the help

Comment: did you have any update/change on python recently?

Comment: no... but I do work a lot in the pydev enviroument, if that matters. Anyway, the debugging of python programs with Pydev works fine and on the other hand, debugging of c/c++ binaries is causing eclipse (and gdb) to show the error mentioned above

Comment: how is it reproduced if you run gdb on command line?

Comment: Hi. it turned out that the problem was that my passwd file got corrupted somehow and was configured to open 'python' instead of bash. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess this has something to do with the python support of gdb.... can you check what gdb is loading by

```
 (gdb) info auto-load python-scripts
```